# Using exception as a data transfer object in reactive extensions

Tags: .net, system.reactive

In Rx there are three main methods: `OnNext<T>`, `OnError` and `OnComplete`, and only `OnNext` is supposed to pass data.

I have time stamped data points and data flow where there are normal values that are passed via OnNext and account for more than 99% of data points. But then, some data points are exceptional, e.g. delayed data or out of order data points that rewrite history. Logically it is next *event* on data that needs special treatment, but not next data in the expected order.

Is it "normal" in this case to pass exceptional values via `OnError` channel? I could define `OutOfOrderDataExcpetion<T> : Exception` with a property of type `T` and process it in an observer. Given that exceptional values are rare and I do not throw/raise exceptions but construct them and use them as DTO, performance should not be a problem.

My concern is that the method is called `OnError` and not `OnException`, but my data is not an error, it just needs special treatment. At the same time, if I expose my observable to external code that knows nothing about `OutOfOrderExcpetion<T>`, the external code would not be able to catch it specifically and that would be an error.

I could follow event sourcing pattern and wrap each data event in a wrapper with a command and payload, but then I will need to unpack each command and in 99%+ cases it will be the same command "next". Using `OnError` as a channel for all other command gives me almost the same event sourcing pattern with a simplified processing.

Other than the naming issue, could you add some arguments that will stop me from using this design? Or this is a proper use of exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a behaviour contract for Rx observables. You are guaranteed zero or more `OnNext` calls, followed by one, and one only, of either `OnError` or `OnCompleted`.

If you use `OnError` then you are saying that **"something went wrong and now the sequence has ended"**.

So you really can't use `OnError` as it is not an "error channel".

It would be simple to use a wrapper if you did it this way:

```
normals
    .Select(data => new { normal = true, data })
    .Merge(
        specials
            .Select(data => new { normal = false, data })
```

Comment: This is a very good point that OnError could be "one, and one only", thanks! Do you have a link to the docs? And if "normal" consumers follow the specs, they will terminate and unsubscribe and won't see the next error, what is exactly the problem with "special subscribers" that will survive special exceptions?

Comment: On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx), the wording is "typically called" for each method, I cannot quickly find a reference to the strict contract that you mention.  "the sequence has ended" is indicated by "OnComplete", why then there is this special completion method if one could use `OperationCancelledException` as in TPL when a task is cancelled by a cancellation token?

Comment: @V.B. - Take a look at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219 - specifically the part about the Rx Grammar - "Messages sent to instances of the IObserver interface follow the following grammar: `OnNext*(OnCompleted|OnError)?`. This grammar allows observable sequences to send any amount (0 or more) of OnNext messages to the subscribed observer instance, optionally followed by a single success (OnCompleted) or failure (OnError) message."

Comment: @V.B. - I don't know what you mean by 'problem with "special subscribers" that will survive special exceptions'?

Comment: @V.B. - Can you be more specific on where `OperationCanceledException` is raised and my what class/operation?

Comment: Tasks use exception to signal their completion with `OperationCanceledException` and their state property, basically they send OnComplete via OnError channel if we compare to Rx. "Special" means written by me - they will know how to handle my exceptions, but external libraries will correctly fail.

Comment: Actually, this discussion and your strong argument about the contract helped me to understand that the design with several exceptional values is bad. I will change my logic so that only one exceptional value breaks the flow. Similarly to "IEnumerable was changed during enumeration" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't use `OnError` for passing data. As you've hinted yourself, bad things may happen.

I don't quite see what's wrong with using a wrapper. You say you don't want to write unwrapping code, but surely, unwillingness is a very odd reason for not doing the right thing. Are there objective reasons for this?

Are you, perhaps, concerned that the unwrapping code would clutter your program? But you don't have to write it all in one place, you can separate it and still have everything look nice. Something like:

```
IObservable<Wrapper> source = ...
var processed = 
    source
    .HandleNormalCase( unwrappedNormalData => { ... } )
    .HandleAbnormalCase( unwrappedExnData => { ... } )
```

Where `.HandleXxx` are extension methods that do the unwrapping.

Comment: But what if some consumer knows only how to process normal data that is passed via `OnNext`, and should fail or start from scratch, while only smart consumers know how to process exceptional data? I.e. bad things should happen for unprepared consumers. A concern with the wrapper is performance: the 99% case is very sensitive to it.